# Is there a word for Questioning your own values?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

We should always question what we think we know. So, is there a word that describes the act of questioning one's beliefs/values/personal philosophy? Can you say, this person should be more (insert word here)?

Comment: The word is "scientific".

Answer (score 4):

As in:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98751?redirectedFrom=introspective#eid)

This person should be more **introspective**.

> Having the quality of looking within; examining into one's own
>   thoughts, feelings, or mental condition, or expressing such
>   examination; of, pertaining to, characterized by, or given to
>   introspection. introspective psychology, psychology based on
>   introspection and on the direct observation of one's own mental
>   states.

Comment: "soul-searching" is good but doesn't apply as well as "introspective" in the sentence context.